# Presenting Random Data Sets

Tags: javascript, random

I currently have 3 Data Sets. We'll call them Step1, Step2, Step3. Each contains at least 6+ items.

```
Step1    Step2     Step3
item     item      item
item     item      item
item     item      item
item     item      item
...      ...       ... And so on
```

The data sets consist of steps one can take to achieve a goal. Which step you pick from each data set does not matter, they just have to be performed in order.

Currently the way I am presenting the data is by using a 3 reel slot machine. You always win at this game, as the slot machine only acts as a way to generate a combination of steps to take. The user simply clicks the spin button and the slot machine randomly selects an item from each reel.

My question/problem here is, are there other ways I could present the information? The slot machine is a fun way to do it but I am wondering if it is the most effective.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can represent your system as a [Graph](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) where each path taken is guaranteed to take you to whatever you define as your "winning" spot. Basically, you have your events, or items, represented as nodes of the graph. The next node must be randomly selected as long as it is not in the same class of the node (steps, as you called it) you are coming from. You must ensure programmatically that each randomly chosen path will bring you to a "winning" destination node.

JavaScript supports libraries that implement such a data structure, which would be useful in the implementation of this. An example of such library is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graph-data-structure#graph).

Comment: Thanks @justin_shapiro, I'll look into this. Just scanning the page it might be what I'm looking for.